# Json Element (JsonPrimitive) trouble converting to JsonObject

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to convert a JsonPrimitive Element to a Json Object but having trouble.  I am using the com.google.gson lib on Android.

The JSON element is returned from a server after a REST call.  The element looks like this.

```JSON
[
  {
    id=95018, 
    date=2015-05-10 08:38:42, 
    message=some text with a long message, 
    from=wbadmin, 
    subject=message subject, 
    lastPostDate=2015-05-10 08:38:42
  }, 
  {
    id=95019, 
    date=2015-05-10 08:38:42, 
    message=some text with a long message, 
    from=wbadmin, 
    subject=message subject, 
    lastPostDate=2015-05-10 08:38:42
  },
  {
    id=95020, 
    date=2015-05-10 08:38:42, 
    message=some text with a long message, 
    from=wbadmin, 
    subject=message subject, 
    lastPostDate=2015-05-10 08:38:42
  }
]
```

So far nothing I have tried seems to work.  Do I have to convert this into a string, escape it and then convert back into JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around the individual records.  See an example here: http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: They are sent from the server with quotes around them but it is returned as a String.  That string is then parsed into a JSON object `code`<br/>JsonObject result = new JsonObject();<br/>
        result.addProperty("result", response);<br/>
        result.addProperty("code", code);<br/>
        result.addProperty("error", error);<br/>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response drdawud.  My comments ended up being a mess so I'll add a little more info here.

The JSON is generated on the server and returned as a string via the rest call.  This string does have the quotes.  That string is then added to a JSON object.

```js
JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
result.addProperty("result", response);
result.addProperty("code", code);
result.addProperty("error", error);
```

That JsonObject is then used elsewhere in the application.  It is extracting that "result" element and accessing the inner elements that I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

OK so found JSON above is actually a JsonArray and not a JsonObject.  My coms Layer was encountering a parse error and dutifully handling the error by converting the response to a String and spitting it back.  I simply changed my JSON to...

```JSON
{
  "Data":
    {
      [
        {
          "id"="95018", 
          "date"="2015-05-10 08:38:42", 
          "message"="some text with a long message", 
          "from"="wbadmin", 
          "subject"="message subject", 
          "lastPostDate"="2015-05-10 08:38:42"
        }, 
        {
          "id"="95019", 
          "date"="2015-05-10 08:38:42", 
          "message"="some text with a long message", 
          "from"="wbadmin", 
          "subject"="message subject", 
          "lastPostDate"="2015-05-10 08:38:42"
        },
        {
          "id"="95020", 
          "date"="2015-05-10 08:38:42", 
          "message"="some text with a long message", 
          "from"="wbadmin", 
          "subject"="message subject", 
          "lastPostDate"="2015-05-10 08:38:42"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Now everything is working fine.